# AttributeError: 'ResizableDraggablePicture' object has no attribute 'scale'

Tags: python, camera, kivy, kivy-language, raspberry-pi4

I'm new to python and Kivy programming so getting trouble and may be asking simple question here, but its a big hurdle for me now. I am developing a GUI with kivy. I have camera and, I have a zoom button.
I want when Clicked on zoom button , zoom in or zoom out picture .
but It's not work and I've get this Error :

```
     if self.scale < 10 :
AttributeError: 'ResizableDraggablePicture' object has no attribute 'scale'
```

and this is my code :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager , Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import time
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (1000, 700)

class ResizableDraggablePicture(Screen):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if touch.is_mouse_scrolling:
            if touch.button == 'scrolldown':
                if self.scale < 10:
                    self.scale = self.scale * 1.1
            elif touch.button == 'scrollup':
                if self.scale > 1:
                    self.scale = self.scale * 0.8
        else:
            super(ResizableDraggablePicture, self).on_touch_down(touch)


class MainPage(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class CameraClick(Screen):
    def capture(self):
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        print("Captured")

     


Builder.load_string("""

#:import utils kivy.utils
<WindowManager>:
    CameraClick:
    ResizableDraggablePicture:

<ResizableDraggablePicture>:
    name :app.root.current = "resizableDraggablePicture"   


<CameraClick>:

    name: "camera"
    orientation: 'vertical'    
    resolution: (1000, 500)

    Camera:
        id: camera
        play: False
        allow_stretch: True
        
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 50 , 50 , 50 , 50
        spacing: 5   

        ToggleButton:
            text: 'Play'
            on_press: camera.play = not camera.play
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '48dp'
        Button:
            text: 'Capture'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '48dp'
            on_press: root.capture()
            
            
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 500 , 400 , 600 , 650
    

        ToggleButton:
            text: 'Zoom'
            font_size:12
            height: 70
            width: 50
            on_press: "resizableDraggablePicture"     

""")

class Shenacell(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        # self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"
        return WindowManager()

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    Shenacell().run()
```

I've delete some extra code here .
anyway When I've run my code and Clicked on Zoom button the screen be white and get that error.

Comment: What do you not understand about the error? It seems clear that `self.scale` is not defined.

Comment: how can I define it ?  Should I install something ?

Comment: No, you should write python code that sets `self.scale` to some value.

Comment: aha ok , you know how can I zoom camera with my Button ? I think It's Wrong...:(